# Is it safe to serialize and unserialize the $_POST array?

Tags: php, security, post, serialization, deserialization

TLDR: Is it safe to serialize the $_POST array to a file and then read it back into the $_POST variable on a different request or a different script?

I realize this is unusual. There is a reason for it, and it would take a dozen pages of text to explain why I am considering doing it in a special case, at least in the meantime.

Boiled down process:

```
file_put_contents('sample.post', serialize($_POST));

$_POST = unserialize(file_get_contents('sample.post'));
```

I already have extensive filtering in place for the actual contents of the post variable. My question is whether or not the process of serializing and unserializing the entire $_POST array is giving a malicious user a method of attack.

The PHP doc says "Warning. Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize(). Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this."

I found these articles that describe this method of attack. But they seem to depend on the user being able to specify the string to unserialize directly, IE unserialize($_POST['value']).

https://www.notsosecure.com/remote-code-execution-via-php-unserialize/
https://heine.familiedeelstra.com/security/unserialize

Am I correct that as long as I am serializing and unserializing, objects can't be created in the unserializing process, right?

I am under the impression that the $_POST array will only ever contain strings (though I couldn't find that explicitly mentioned in the PHP docs).

As I understand it, even if someone supplies a string matching the format of a serialized object, it will be 'stored' as a string during serialization, with an explicit length (byte length). So it will just be assigned as a string when unserializing. It seems like since the lengths of the strings are stored along with them during serialization, you can't break the structure of a serialized string from the input like you might with SQL injection. I tried to trick it with some invalid multi-byte characters, but no luck. However, me being unable to do it and experienced hackers being able to do it are 2 different things.

I couldn't find anything else about other attack methods.

Please let me know if I'm missing something! I just read several comments saying 'you should never do this', so I'm nervous that I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: looks like you have your bases covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible without further attacks to send something as a POST variable to exploit the `unserialize()` call later in your scenario, but others may probably have an idea. It could be a problem if $_POST had something unserializable, but I think that may not happen. Whatever was in $_POST, it was already in memory once, so assuming `serialize()` and `unserialize()` work correctly, it should be secure to do something like

```
$serialized = serialize($userinput);
unserialize($serialized);
```

However, you are saving this data to disk inbetween. After exploiting a different flaw and having access to your files (or having access "by design", like IT ops staff), an attacker may be able to modify saved serialized data, and may inject his attack there. That way it would obviously be vulnerable.

So it is indeed a risk, albeit maybe not a very high one. Be aware that the security of this solution depends a lot on security of your saved serialized content.

Comment: Can somebody plz kindly explain the downvote? I am happy to amend or remove my answer if you tell me why it's wrong.